# Hibernate selecting collection as column in a single query

Tags: java, hibernate

I have 3 entities as follows

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    int userId;
    String name;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    List<Address> addressList = new ArrayList<Address>();

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    List<Vehicle> vehicles =  new ArrayList<Vehicle>();
    public User(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public User(String name) {this.name=name;}

    public User(List<Address> addressList) {this.addressList = addressList;}
    /**
    * getters amd setters
    */
}

@Entity
public class Address {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int addressId;

    private String city;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "VEHICLE")
public class Vehicle {

    @Id
    private int idVehcle;
    private String manufacturer;
}
```

I need select get the users as *User* objects in a **single query** which contains addressList but not vehicles.

Both Address and Vehicles entities are Eager and I can't change that because there is already a lots of code around it. So if I try to get users in hql and it contains n rows there will be n additional queries for addressList and another n queries for vehicles (performance issue).

If I try this

```
  String hql = "SELECT new User(u.name) FROM User  u";
  List<User> users = session.createQuery(hql).list();
```

Only one query will be executed and only name field will be selected.
But if I try this

```
 String hql = "SELECT new User(u.addressList) FROM User  u";
 List<User> users = session.createQuery(hql).list();
```

En exception is thrown because of the generated sql. Does anybody has solution to this.

> Looks like https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=991742 they are having the same problems too.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new User class where the Vehicles are not eager and then use that for selecting. If you extend the User class you could get away with adding very little code

```
@Entity
public class User2 extends User {

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
List<Vehicle> vehicles =  new ArrayList<Vehicle>();

public User2(String name) {super(name);}

public User2(List<Address> addressList) {super(addressList);}
}
```

This assumes your User class has at least protected access which it is in your example.

Comment: Can you please elaborate, perhaps with some code example ?